# Build failed ionic 2

Tags: cordova, angular, npm, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic 2 app and it was working well, but a while ago I installed [insomnia plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/insomnia/) and now I can't build the production version!

If I do:
`$ionic run android` or `$ionic run android --consolelogs --livereload`, it works well and Insomia works fine.

But, now when I do:

```
$ionic build android --prod --release
```

I get:

```
build prod failed: Cannot read property 'Plugin' of undefined, resolving symbol Insomnia in /media/....blabla.../node_modules/@ionic-native/insomnia/index.d.ts
```

I followed the steps of the official documentation. ([insomnia plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/insomnia/))

Thank's so much in advance!!!

**EDIT:**

When I installed the Insomnia plugin I had this but I did not give importance because I got it previous times:

```
├── @ionic-native/insomnia@3.4.4 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/core@2.2.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.2.1 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic-angular@2.1.0 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
```

**packaje.json:**

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/insomnia": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.1.1",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.6-preview",
    "firebase": "^3.6.4",
    "ionic-angular": "^2.1.0",
    "ionic-native": "^2.5.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "soundcloud": "^3.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.3",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "Mindfulness: An Ionic project"
}
```

**config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.mindfulness924927" version="0.0.55" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>Visión Clara</name>
  <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
  <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png"/>
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.10:8000"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.47:8000"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.120.57:8000"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.120.54:8000"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.120.60:8000"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.120.51:8000"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.120.53:8000"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.120.52:8000"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.120.55:8000"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.120.54:8100"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.10:8100"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.43.177:8100"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.47:8100"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.120.55:8100"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.120.50:8100"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~2.0.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.3.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-http" spec="~1.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" spec="~2.4.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.1"/>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
</widget>
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-purchase": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/insomnia": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/local-notifications": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/media": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/screenshot": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.1.1",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.6-preview",
    "firebase": "^3.6.4",
    "ionic-angular": "^2.1.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "soundcloud": "^3.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.3",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
  "description": "Mindfulness: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: can you show the `package.json` file?

Comment: and `config.xml` file?

Comment: @Sampath Sure, done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error, and solved it updating Angular dependencies as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/calendar": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/contacts": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.4.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "chance": "^1.0.6",
    "firebase": "^3.7.4",
    "ionic-angular": "2.3.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "uglify-js": "^2.8.22",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "@types/gapi": "0.0.30",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here `"ionic-native": "^2.5.1",`.You have to remove this from your `package.json` file and after that run `npm i`.You cannot keep both latest `"@ionic-native/core": "^3.4.4",` and old one.You didn't upgrade the native module properly.So now you have to do that as mentioned above.Before do that keep a backup of your project.

You have to implement your plugins as `providers`.Please [**see this doc**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/).

**Update:**

*uninstall*

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-statusbar --save

npm uninstall @ionic-native/status-bar --save
```

*install*

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar --save 

npm install --save @ionic-native/status-bar
```

Comment: But, if I remove `ionic-native` , Will not work all the plugins it contains? For example: `import { InAppPurchase } from 'ionic-native';`

Comment: So,  should I install all the ionic-native plugins like `npm install --save @ionic-native/status-bar`?

I already deleted `"ionic-native": "^2.5.1"` from packaje.json and I did `npm i`

Comment: Yes, That is the safest method.

Comment: Thank you, I'll tell you in a moment if it went well or bad haha

Comment: I did it. And I have the same issue but now with another plugin:

`build prod failed: Cannot read property 'Plugin' of undefined, resolving symbol StatusBar in 
            /media/......../node_modules/@ionic-native/status-bar/index.d.ts `

Comment: With `ionic serve` or `ionic run android` it runs well... but I can't do: `ionic build android --prod --release`

Comment: Done, see the "EDIT 2" above, please

Comment: update this too. `"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",`.after that `npm i`

Comment: Ok, updated to 1.1.4 but still having the same error :(

Comment: When I do: `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-statusbar --save`
I have `Error: Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-nativeaudio". Please try adding it again.`

But I don't use a nativeaudio plugin. I installed it a long time ago and then do not use it

Comment: just add it again.

Comment: Ok I unistalled and re installed StatusBar plugin but stll having the same error:  `build prod failed: Cannot read property 'Plugin' of undefined, resolving symbol StatusBar in 
            /media/ivan/Cosas 
            importantes/Trabajo/AnimaEdu/animaedu-mobile/node_modules/@ionic-native/status-bar/index.d.ts`

Comment: do this too. `ionic platform rm android` after that `ionic platform add android`

Comment: I did it. Reinstalled platform android but the problem persist. I have the same error.
As well as app-scripts, will not it be necessary to update something else?

Comment: Hmmmm... are you in an early stage of your app's development or old app? is there any possibility to create a new project and `copy/paste` your custom items to a new project?

Comment: The app began to develop about three and a half months ago. At one point I had to upgrade the project. If I create a new project, I do not know if I can then link it to the private repository of the company and work from this new one or there could be a problem. I also do not know the steps I should take if I create a new project. You could tell me how to do? Once I wanted to do it and I failed in the attempt. I do not know if I have to install the plugins one by one, or how to do it.

Comment: Mmmm I think I can't, because we have already published the app in play store and is the version number 53. If I create a new project I need to reconfigure the app with facebook analytics, create a new app in firebase and link it, create a new keystore, a new app in play store. I'm not sure if I can do that :/

Comment: Yep, then it'll be very difficult task.Hope you can raise this issue on official git repo too. Maybe you'll have a better solution there.try that too. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/new

Comment: Thank you so much! I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/1311)

Comment: Ok, Great.No problem  :)